# windows.scrollBy adding a fixed scrolling value to top

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, scroll

I have this function I'm using it in my AngularJS directive. This function scrolls to the top of the page, but this is not what I am aiming to do: I want to make it scroll up just 400px or 30%.

```
function scrollToTop() {
    var scrollDuration = 500;
    var scrollStep = -window.scrollY / (scrollDuration / 15);
    console.log(scrollStep);

    var scrollInterval = setInterval(function () {
        if (window.scrollY != 0) {
           window.scrollBy(0, scrollStep);
        } else {
           clearInterval(scrollInterval);
        }
    }, 15);
}
```

I tried changing the `scrollStep` variable to be 300 or any other number but I can't understand it actually.

Comment: "I want to make it scroll up just 400px or 30%" can you please explain that in more detail?

Comment: @FreemanLambda Hey. What is happening now that when i fire this function from a button at the bottom of my page. The screen scroll to top of the page but i want it to just scroll 400 px or any other number not to the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total `distanceToScroll` is either an arbitrary number of pixels (i.e 400) or the whole window-scroll distance if it is less than 400. For that you can use `Math.min`. `scrollStep` is calculated dependently from `distanceToScroll`. You need to keep a count of "how much I've scrolled so far" in the `setInterval`, lets call it `distanceScrolled`. Keep scrolling until you have covered the `distanceToScroll`.

```js
function scrollToTop() {
    var scrollDuration = 500;
    var stepDuration = 15;
    
    var distanceToScroll = Math.min(400, window.scrollY);
    
    var scrollStep = distanceToScroll / (scrollDuration / stepDuration);
    console.log(scrollStep);

    var distanceScrolled = 0;

    var scrollInterval = setInterval(function () {
        if (distanceScrolled < distanceToScroll) {
           window.scrollBy(0, -1 * scrollStep);
           distanceScrolled += scrollStep
        } else {
           clearInterval(scrollInterval);
        }
    }, stepDuration);
}

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', scrollToTop);
```

```css
#very-high {
  height: 3000px;
}

#btn {
  position: fixed;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="very-high"></div>
<button id="btn">Scroll</button>
```

Comment: Oh man thank you so much really. You explained to me how i should think about it and solved for me. really thank you i appreciate this really.